# Error de validacion numerica Laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, validación

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'carnet' => 'required|max:12|min:5',
        .
        .
        .
        'required|before_or_equal:'.$hoy.'|after_or_equal:'.$fecha_minima.'|date',
        'telefono' => 'max:10|numeric',
        .
        .
        .
    ]);
```

Bien, tengo un problema con las validaciones. Como ven tengo un campo llamado ´telefono´ al cual estoy validando. Quiero asignarle solo dos validaciones, `numeric|max:12` el problema es que si le pongo la validacion de `numeric` me arroja un error con la longitud. Y me dice que solo puede tener 12 digitos. Pero el input de entrada tiene solo 8. Si le quito el `numeric` funciona bien, pero si se lo pongo me arroja el problema. No se porque.

El campo carnet no me da problemas porque no es numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Bien la respuesta que encontré es la siguiente.
En realidad, el `max y min` miden la longitud de una cadena. Cuando se trata de un numero, miden como tal el valor numerico. Por ende, si quieres que el numero tenga `max:10`, no deberias poner el `10` sino `9999999999`.

Por otro lado, encontre que es mejor guardar el `telefono` como una cadena de texto, ya que de todas formas no haras ningun calculo matematico con ese numero.

Esto responde el problema de porque la validacion no funcionaba. Ahora, si quieres que validar que no se ingresen letras en ese campo, puedes usar del lado de `front` los `input type numeric` o una regla de escritura con `JS`. Y del lado de backend, podrias validarlo con `is_numeric()` o algo asi. Si alguien sabe como hacerlo con las reglas de validacion de Laravel, su ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Si optas por esta opción, simplemente comentar que las validaciones de números a veces pueden ser verdaderas e incluir caracteres como ```` e E + - ```` debido a la notación científica, si quieres validar que solo sean números lo mejor es utilizar expresiones regulares, en particular el (````\d````).